# Draw the outline of a shape in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to draw a rectangle in react native with a black outline and transparent center. I am able to draw a rectangle but I am not able to make its center transparent. Here is an expo example of how I'm drawing a rectangle: https://snack.expo.dev/@melampus123/rectangle-drawing

and here is my desired image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [ViewStyleProps](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props) in react-native.

I modified your example and commented here: https://snack.expo.dev/@pqv2210/rectangle-drawing